# Problems decrypting HTTP Live Stream

Tags: http, stream, openssl, live, encryption

I have a single key encrypted HTTP Live Stream which decodes fine in Quicktime and iPhone.  I'm trying to create a simple client application to do the decryption of the ts files.  Right now I've used openssl to decrypt.  I believe I have the correct arguments to openssl and I'm inserting the key and the IV properly.  I can successfully decrypt the first .ts file in the stream but fail to decrypt after.  I'm using the following script which I found in the archives here and I reversed to do decryption:

```
#!/bin/sh

hexKey=$(cat encryption.key | hexdump-e '16/1 "%02x"') 
hexIV='00000000000000000000000000000001' 
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in ./multi_2.ts -out ./clear.ts -p-nosalt -iv ${hexIV}  -K ${hexKey}
```

where:

encryption.key is the key file I retrieved from the M3u8 stream file.
multi_2.ts is the second .ts file in the m3u8 stream file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ryan can you tell me how to run your script . i need to decrypt a list of .ts files with single key. should i run that in dos ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subsequent .ts files are probably fine, you just need to join them into one file in order to be playable:

```
cat clear*.ts > joined.ts
```

Comment: Yep, that was the trick.  I was wondering why they needed to be joined.  The spec seems to indicate that while its OK for the follow transport streams to contain less metadata in the header they should contain enough data to be played back individually.

Answer (score 0):

`hexIV='00000000000000000000000000000001'`

should be :

`hexIV='00000000000000000000000000000002'`

as multi_2.ts is the second .ts file in the m3u8 stream file.